# NSTime update when button selected

Tags: ios, button, uiviewcontroller, uikit, nstimer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your counter is: %d",seconds];
    seconds = 0;
    randomTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomMainVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)randomMainVoid{
    seconds += 1;
    counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your counter is: %d",seconds];
}

-(IBAction)Green:(id)sender{
    seconds+=2;
    colorLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    colorLabel.text = @"Your color is: Green";
}
```

My first method is updating the seconds and displaying it. I have a button, when I click it i want the seconds to go up double. How would I do that?

Comment: Is the above code having any issue.?

Comment: Why do you use seconds+=2 not seconds*=2 ?

Comment: There is no issues. It won't update the score to times 2

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking.  Are you wanting the seconds to start increasing by 2 after the button is pressed?  Or are you wanting pressing the button to add 2 to seconds (which it's doing now)

Comment: @David I would like it to start increasing by 2 after the button is pressed. Sorry for not being clear.